# how to delete records in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

can anybody tell me how to delete records from the database?
I'm done with the rest part only deletion remains. I'm running the deletion command but 
the data is not deleted from the database.Actuaaly i created an action in controller(delete_user) which contains the code for deleting the user from the database.
email value is stored in a session and i'm accessing it;s value using session read function
in the next controller.

`function delete_user()
      {
     $email=$this->Session->read('User.email');
         $this->User->delete($email, $cascade = true);
         echo $this->Session->delete('User.email');
        echo $this->Session->delete('User.username');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login')); 
      }   );`

i'm creating a link in home(View) page. and it is like this.

```
a href='/cakephp/cakephp/Users/delete_user'>Delete Profile</a>
```

i'm doing it right or wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the online [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html) first before asking such a question.

#### Update 18/10/12

Try using CakePhp's magic find types:

```
$user = $this->User->findByEmail("bob@gmail.com");
$this->User->delete($user['User']['id']);
```

Comment: yes I Did this.I knw how to do it. but I tried both the method means using id(int) and email(varchar). But it is not deleting the data.

Comment: thnks delany..for your answer....it's working...grt yaar(friend)..thnks very much....

Answer (score 3):

In your controller replace  following code with delete action:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this->User->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

and in ctp file add the following link:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', ID OF THE RECORD, null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', ID OF THE RECORD)); ?>
```

then your problem will be solved...

Answer (score 1):

you just need to pass the id as a first parameter:

```
$this->User->delete($id, $cascade);
```

Comment: ya i'm passing the email id. i'm deleting the data on the behalf of email id, hence here my email id will be considered as particular id because it is unique for everyone.

Comment: but in this case i'm using email id....which is also unique for every person. then why don't it's working? i tried this using id(int) also but in that case it is also not deleting  any data.

Answer (score 0):

with this you can delete it without cascade:

```
 $this->Todo->delete($this->request->data('Todo.id'));
```

you can hook into this befor with

```
function beforeDelete(){

}
```

and here is my full delete action:

```
function delete($id = null){

     $this->Todo->recursive = 1;

            // new
            $todo = $this->Todo->read(null,$id);
            if($id == null || $todo == null) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Todo existiert nicht.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                return;
            }
            $this->set('todo',$todo);
            $this->Todo->delete($this->request->data('Todo.id'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            return;


}
```